# Jedis with SAVE command on AWS Elasticache (Redis)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, redis, jedis, amazon-elasticache

The following comes from a Tomcat Server in AWS, where we have a Redis Elasticache instance setup:

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR unknown command 'SAVE'
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:127)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:161)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:215)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:340)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:239)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.save(BinaryJedis.java:2700)
at cl.waypoint.util.CacheReports.setCacheReports(CacheReports.java:51)
at cl.waypoint.reports3.ReportStatus.setProgress(ReportStatus.java:86)
at cl.waypoint.reports3.Report101.getData(Report101.java:210)
at cl.waypoint.reports3.Report101.createXLS(Report101.java:274)
at cl.waypoint.reports3.ReportStatus.run(ReportStatus.java:38)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Seems like Elasticache is missing support for such command, as Redis by itself does support it. Any ideas or workarounds would be appreciated

PS1: Jedis v2.9.0 and the Elasticache instance has Engine Version Compatibility: 3.2.4

PS2: I've just asked the same question to AWS support as sadly I've had no feedback at all here :(

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked at [Redisson](https://redisson.org)? Some Redis commands are not available in AWS Elasticache `SAVE` command is one of them. Here is full list of such [commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/ClientConfig.RestrictedCommands.html). Despite of such limitations Redisson has solid integration with AWS Elasticache.

Here is an code example to use it with AWS Elasticache:

```
// 1. Create config object
Config config = new Config();
config.useReplicatedServers()
    .addNodeAddress("redis://first-node.aws.com:7000", "redis://second-node.aws.com:7001");

// 2. Create Redisson instance
RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);

// 3. Get object you need
RMap<MyKey, MyValue> map = redisson.getMap("myMap");

RLock lock = redisson.getLock("myLock");

RExecutorService executor = redisson.getExecutorService("myExecutorService");

// over 30 different objects and services are available...
```